# Markov processes with positive jump probability at fixed time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I would expect this question to be answered somewhere but I can't find it. I have the following conjecture.

Let $X=(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a time homogeneous (strong?) Markov process with cadlag paths on some general state space (e.g. Polish metric space) and let $s >0$. Then for all starting points $x\in S$
$$
 P_x(X_s \neq X_{s-}) = 0,
$$
where $X_{s-} =\lim_{t\uparrow s} X_t$ denotes the left limit point $X$ at time $s$.
In other words, $X$ is almost surely continuous at any fixed time.

I strongly believe that there is a contradiction to time homogeneity if we assume that there is a time point $s>0$ with strictly positive jump probability but I have been unable to construct such a contradiction.

I would be very thankful for any hints on a proof or pointers to relevant literature.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a partial answer to my question in the book of Chung and Walsh (Markov Processes Brownian Motion, and Time Symmetry, https://doi.org/10.1007/0-387-28696-9). In Proposition 2.2.2 they show that Feller processes are *stochastically continuous* in the sense that $X_s \rightarrow X_t$ in probability (under every initial distribution) as $s \rightarrow t$.